# Dividing one column of a data frame by another: avoid to divide by zero

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to devide the values of one column in a data frame by the corresponding values of another column. Whenever the second column is 0 (zero) the result should not be `Inf` but `NA`. At the moment I have the following solution:

```
d<-data.frame(x=1:10, y=sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE))
d$z <- d$x / d$y
d[d$z==Inf,]$z<-NA
```

However, is there a way to avoid the replacement of `Inf` by `NA` in the 3rd statement, e.g. by using something like a conditional statement in the 2nd operation `d$x / d$y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to do a test of `y`, and then pick the correct operation based on that test, like so:

```
d$z<-ifelse(d$y==0, NA, d$x/d$y)
```