# If else function for R

Tags: r, if-statement

My dataframe is as follow:

```
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Currency : Factor w/ 3 levels "EUR","GBP","USD": 3 3 1 2 3 1 2
 $ Amount.LC: int  100 500 400 200 350 100 500
 $ FX.Rate  : Factor w/ 3 levels "0,89","1,201",..: 2 2 3 1 2 3 1
```

Based on an "if-else" function I tried to calculate a new column, called Amount.GC, depending whether a "EUR" is in column Currency or not. If "EUR" than I want to have the same value as in column Amount.LC. Else I want to have the division of Amount.LC and FX.Rate (Amount.LC/FX.Rate).

My code is as follow:

```
for (i in df$Currency){if (i == "EUR"){df$Amount.GC <- df$Amount.LC}
else{df$Amount.GC <- c(df$Amount.LC)/c(df$FX.Rate)}}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Could someone please help me?

Comment: [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408736/dividing-one-column-of-a-data-frame-by-another-avoid-to-divide-by-zero)

Comment: Read about `ifelse` no need for `forloop`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you dont need a forloop for it. You can do everything in the ifelse condition and assign the results directly to the new column.

```
df = data.frame(
  Currency = sample(c("EUR", "GBP", "USD"), size = 10, replace = T),
  Amount.LC = sample(c(100,200,300,400,500), size=10, replace = T),
  FX.Rate = sample(c(0.89, 1.201, 1,5), size=10, replace=T)
)


df$Amount.GC = ifelse(df$Currency == "EUR", df$Amount.LC, (df$Amount.LC/df$FX.Rate))

df
```